# Problemas al tratar de Publicar Proyecto Web en IIS7 desde Visual Studio 2017

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2017

Saludos amigos:

Mi problema consiste en que estoy tratando de publicar un proyecto web en el IIS desde visual studio eligiendo la ubicacion de la carpeta correspondiente"c:\inetpup\wwwroot\miProyecto", pero cuando presiono en publicar solo me muestra el mensaje de "Preparando perfil", y en eso se tardo mas de 12 horas.

Ya trate de crear un nuevo perfil, pero al intentarlo no me habre las ventana de opciones para crearlo.

Espero haber logrado darme a entender y les agradeceria cualquier ayuda.

NOTA: El proyecto ya habia estado publicado, pero al aplicar algunos cambios con un control de versiones, perdi el perfil y el problema surge al tratar de crearlo de nuevo.

Comment: Intenta de otra forma...por ejemplo crea el empaquetado en zip, e importa la aplicacion desde IIS

Comment: En la carpeta de propiedades del proyecto borra todos los perfiles de publicación y crea un perfil de nuevo.

Comment: Es anormal que se demore tanto, quizás haya problemas en el disco duro. Por otro lado, ¿lograste solucionarlo?